# AngularJS typeahead - show also versions of file with checkbox to select

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use following code in my application:

```
           <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Search document" 
                   data-ng-model="file"
                   typeahead="document as document.fileName for document in vm.findDocumentsByTerm($viewValue)"
                   typeahead-min-length="2"
                   typeahead-wait-ms="100"
                   typeahead-editable="false"
                   typeahead-on-select="vm.attachFile(file)" />
```

and I not only will show the fileName (document.fileName) but also the versions of the document (document.versions) which is an array and a checkbox in order to select a version of the document.
Is there a possibility to do this?

**[EDIT]**
thanks to yeslcan, it was exactly what I need. Currently it looks like this:

[image: dropdown]

And this is my html code:

```
<input type="text" 
   class="form-control" 
   data-ng-model="file"
   typeahead="document as document.fileName for document in vm.findDocumentsByTerm($viewValue)"
   typeahead-template-url = "sampleTemplate.htm"  />
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="sampleTemplate.htm">
  <div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <td>{{match.model.fileName}}</b></td>           
            <td>
                <div data-ng-repeat="documentFileVersion in match.model.documentFileVersions">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="vm.documentFileVersion" data-ng-click="vm.addDocumentFile(vm.documentFileVersion)" /> {{documentFileVersion.version}}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 </script>
```

Currently the function **vm.addDocumentFile(vm.documentFileVersion)** is not invoked. Does anyone know what I have to do in order to invoke this function?

Comment: I don't understand your question, please clarify

Comment: with the posted code only the document filenames are shown in drop down menu, my question would be if it is possible to show the document filename and the corresponding versions (versions is an arrray of document)

Comment: You mean for each document there should be an option per version available for that document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure I fully understand your question I think you can create a template (e.eg. sampleTemplate.html) with content like this (change the formatting as you see fit)

```
<div>
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.fileName + match.model.version | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    </div>
```

then
use the template

```
class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Search document" 
               data-ng-model="file"
               typeahead="document as document.fileName for document in vm.findDocumentsByTerm($viewValue)"
               typeahead-min-length="2"
               typeahead-wait-ms="100"
               typeahead-editable="false"
               typeahead-on-select="vm.attachFile(file)"
               typeahead-template-url =  "sampleTemplate.htm" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its exactly the design I need!! do you know how I can my function invokeable in service - data-ng-click="vm.addDocumentFile(vm.documentFileVersion)" does not invoke the function in my AngularJS service. Thanks!!

Comment: do you know how I can my function invokeable in service?

Comment: please clarify what you mean ?